# UR5 use catesian coordinates in ur_driver test_move.py

Tags: ros, cartesian, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i would like to write some catesian coordinates in test_move.py but i can only change the joint positions.

Has anyone an idea?

Link to test_move.py:
https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/hydro-devel/ur_driver/test_move.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200955/ur5-use-catesian-coordinates-in-ur_driver-test_move.py/) by [Jan Moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21179/jan-moritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in the [MoveIt ComputerCartesianPath](http://moveit.ros.org/doxygen/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#ada4a156dc93edc921f15742394475c60) function. Apparently it is also supported by the Python wrappers, but I don't know how well it works there (see [Python ComputeCartesianPath](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/dJYiQayhA6I) on moveit-users).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jan Moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21179/jan-moritz/) on 2015-01-14**:
I am looking for something like this, that's right. But I don't want to use moveit.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-14**:
Then I guess you'll have to do the IK yourself for all the points that you want in your trajectory. MoveIt includes a service that you can use for that. Alternatively, you could perhaps make use of the libraries in the `ur_kinematics` package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-14**:
Note that not using MoveIt will also mean that you'll have to do collision checking yourself.

**Comment by [Jan Moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21179/jan-moritz/) on 2015-01-15**:
Thank you very much for the answer. This was very helpful =)